# How to create time sheet approver in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i am new to stack overflow and also newbie to Sharepoint. I want to create a approver for approving the time sheet in Sharepoint 2010.The approver should be able to approve all the time-sheets. how can i do that?

Comment: Please post sharepoint questions at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Create One New user and Add that user to the Approvers group for that TimeSheet List.

IF you dont understand then let me know